# How to construct HtmlPage for parsing using WebClient when html file is saved locally?

Tags: java, webclient

I have a html page saved locally with file path

"C:/Users/Kamil/git/RealSuperCoolTeam/src/main/resources/sfq.html"

I need to create a HtmlPage (gargoylesoftware libraries). However, when I pass my local file path into the function which would download the webpage I am receiving errors. It would normally work if passing in a hosted website link.

I have tried swapping the "/" to "\" but it doesn't seem to work.

```
textfieldSfqUrl.setText("C:/Users/Kamil/git/RealSuperCoolTeam/src/main/resources/sfq.html");
    String url = textfieldSfqUrl.getText(); //url stores local file path
    System.out.println("url : " + url);
    HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);

}
```

Expected result : HTML page is saved into the HtmlPage data structure
Actual Result : Throws many errors

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the errors that were thrown?

Comment: I actually managed to fix it. Turns out you need to specify file:///C:/.... before your file path. I guess it's just a system thing.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

You must put "file:///" before the file path.

What would work:

file:///C:/Users/Kamil/git/RealSuperCoolTeam/src/main/resources/sfq.html

instead of

C:/Users/Kamil/git/RealSuperCoolTeam/src/main/resources/sfq.html